# Не работает программа на C++?

Tags: c++, строки

Почему после ввода N нет приглашения ввести boof? программа просто завершается
и ничего не выводит. Компилировала в Dev-C++.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
int main() { 
system("chcp 1251"); 
system("cls"); 

int N,i,j, date=0, older_date=21001231,count=0; 
char boof[50],older[40];

cin>>N;

while(N--)
{
cin.getline(boof,50);
for(i=4; i<=10; i+=3)
  date += atol(&boof[strlen(boof) - i])*pow(100,3-(i/3));       

    if(older_date > date) {
            count=1;
            older_date = date;
            strncpy(older, boof, strlen(boof)- 10);
    } 
    else if(older_date == date) {
        count++;
    }
}

if( count-1 )
    cout<<count<<' '<<older_date;
else
    cout<<older<<' '<<older_date;
}
```

Имеется список людей с указанием их фамилии, имени и даты рождения. Напишите эффективную     по времени работы и по используемой памяти программу (укажите используемую версию языка  программирования,  например,  Borland  Pascal  7.0),  которая  будет  определять  самого  старшего  человека из этого списка и выводить его фамилию и имя, а если имеется несколько самых старших      людей с одинаковой датой рождения, то определять их количество.

На  вход  программе  в  первой  строке  подается  количество  людей  в  списке  N.  В  каждой  из  последующих N строк находится информация в следующем формате:

```
    <Фамилия> <Имя> <Дата рождения>
```

где <Фамилия> – строка, состоящая не более, чем из 20 символов без пробелов, <Имя> – строка,  состоящая не более, чем из 20 символов без пробелов, <Дата рождения> – строка, имеющая вид  ДД.ММ.ГГГГ, где ДД  – двузначное число от 01 до 31, ММ  – двузначное число от 01 до 12, ГГГГ  –  четырехзначное число от 1800 до 2100.

Пример входной строки:

```
    Иванов Сергей 27.03.1993
```

Программа должна вывести фамилию и имя самого старшего человека в списке.
Пример выходных данных:

```
    Иванов Сергей
```

Если  таких людей,  несколько,  то  программа  должна  вывести  их  количество.  Пример  вывода в  этом случае:

```
    3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну, как минимум, стандартная, классическая, сотни раз на этом сайте разобранная ошибка - отсутствие сброса буфера

```
cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(),'\n');
```

после чтения N и перед чтением `buf`, и-з-за чего в `buf` попадает пустая строка.

Что вы делает дальше - это какая-то *жестокось*, по крайней мере, понять по коду, чего вы добиваетесь, я не в состоянии. Если поясните, что должна делать ваша программа - будем смотреть дальше... Даже в учебном задании необходимы как минимум комментарии и приглашения ввода, поясняющие, что должно быть введено...

Пока, например, с чего решено, что `strlen(boof) >= 10`? А без происходит этого явное нарушение границ памяти... Если уж строка должна быть такая длинная (что в ней вообще должно быть?), то это условие надо проверять.

**Update**

Брр. Тогда вы все делаете совсем не так... Во-первых, вам надо хранить имя и фамилию как минимум самого старшего, а еще лучше - всех (так вам будет проще. Без этого можно обойтись, но вам, как начинающей, лучше хранить весь ввод).

```
struct Person
{
    string name, surname;
    int birthday;
};
vector<Person> ps;

cin >> N;
for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
{
    Person p;
    cin >> p.name >> p.surname;
    int d,m,y;
    char c;
    cin >> d >> c >> m >> c >> y;
    p.birthday = y*10000+m*100+d;
    ps.push_back(p);
}
```

После этого у вас в векторе - все люди, причем в полях `birthdate` их дни рождения - в непосредственно сравниваемом виде, с помощью `<`: `yyyymmdd`, типа, 20040220.

Дальше начинайте искать самых старых, теперь это просто.

Спрашивать, что дальше - не рекомендую: здесь *помогают*, а не *решают за вас*...

Comment: Программа должна делать segfault - на большее она не годится

Comment: @misdeed Для этого есть более простые способы... Но если ее подправить, то она что-то все же делает и выдает... Но понять, что она делает и как трактовать ее вывод - я не могу.